# Different size of expected malloc function

Tags: c++, size, malloc

the solution may be trivial but I'm not vivid in cpp.

after I execute code the value of `function strlen((char*)buffer)` is higher than I suppose. Why is that? How can i fix it? 
(`if filesize=48, than strlen((char*)buffer)=64` and it should be also 48!)

```
    ifstream iffile;
    iffile.open(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (iffile.is_open())
    {
       long filesize = iffile.tellg();
       if (filesize > 0)
       {
           iffile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
           {
                 long pos = iffile.tellg();
                 if (pos != filesize)
                 {
                       char *buffer;
                       buffer = (char *)malloc(filesize * sizeof * buffer);
                       if (buffer != NULL)
                       {
                             memset(buffer, 0, filesize - pos);
                             iffile.read((char *)buffer, filesize);
```

Moreover I have to mention that in my file there is a lot of unprintable values.

Comment: When `strlen` encounters a zero byte it will stop counting, perhaps a zero byte exists at position 64 in your buffer

Comment: strlen() will count up to the first '\0' only.

Comment: `filesize * sizeof * buffer` WTF?

Comment: `malloc` and `memset` have no place in C++ code – particularly not high-level code. Moreover, the whole code is riddled with … “interesting” actions.

Comment: @aleguna: It is legal to use `sizeof` without parentheses for unary expressions, only for types they are mandatory. `sizeof * buffer` is therefore the same as `sizeof(*buffer)`, or in this case `sizeof(char)` (but very misleading code style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that the file contains a terminating `'\0'` character, to make the array of characters into a string. This terminator is what `strlen()` looks for, so if it's not there you must add it.

One way to be sure is to `malloc()` (which should be `new[]` or something fancier in C++, by the way) 1 character more than `file_size`, and set that to `'\0'` after loading.

Also, you must check that the allocation and I/O succeed.

Comment: There are probably even fewer good uses of `new[]` in C++ than there are of `malloc`.

Comment: buffer = (char *)malloc(filesize * sizeof * buffer + 1);
and using memset() as you said solved the puzzle. I should really read more about binary operation in cpp style...
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Never use `malloc` in C++; it is a C-ism.

#### Option 1

Use `new` instead;

```
buffer = new char[filesize]
```

You must use `delete[]` to deallocate the memory when you are finished with it.

#### Option 2

You should never use raw pointers in C++ either (well, you can if you know what you are doing and are feeling 100%, have a good cup of coffee and are generally brave).

In this case, I think I would use a `std::vector<char>`.

```
std::vector<char> buffer(filesize);
iffile.read(&buffer.front(), filesize);
```

This way, the `std` library manages the memory for you.